# Synonymous hanjas list (most frequent ones)

Tags: word-usage, hanja

We know that there are at least 2500 hanjas that are used in modern Korean.

I want to know synonymous hanjas like 불 and 무 (무료 and 불합격). These two hanjas are kind of negation prefixes.

There might be synonymous hanjas that mean big or the best or the most or any other word ( I am just guessing here).

So, what are some similar in meaning hanjas used in Korean?

Comment: https://hanja.dict.naver.com/category/syn?q=%E3%84%B1&page=1 could help.

Comment: great help, I will digest and put this in a more exteneded answer if you dont mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a great start would be using as a reference the certificate which specifically tests for Hanja, the [Korean Hanja Proficiency Test](https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%EC%A0%84%EA%B5%AD%ED%95%9C%EC%9E%90%EB%8A%A5%EB%A0%A5%EA%B2%80%EC%A0%95%EC%8B%9C%ED%97%98).

It has a section that tests for synonyms 동의어(유의어) and another for antonyms 반의어(상대어) and those topics are present from level 6급 (8급 is the lowest of all) to 1급 and special 특급.

There is this [blog post](https://blog.naver.com/kwonjr1004/221527942854) which contains some of the synonyms for level 6 (see picture below)

[image: Some hanja synonyms for level 6]

You can see [this online lesson for the 한자능력검정시험](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q0EeZonNMwM) which
encompasses some of the hanja synonyms of level 3 (which should be already a bit advanced, testing around 2000 characters).

Finally, there is [this general list](https://hanjatop.tistory.com/71) of hanja-based synonym words that appear on multiple levels of the proficiency test.